# Issue with KendoNumericTextbox in KendoWindow

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-window, kendonumerictextbox

I'm trying to create a modal window with a kendo textbox on fly, the text box is added successfully into the form but its validation rules do not work. The source code is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/romanshakhov/3rbj9yks/4/). Is it possible to resolve this issue?

The container is

```
<div id="wnd"></div>
```

The text box is created with the code:

```
var numeric = $('<input>').kendoNumericTextBox({
min: 0,
max: 32767,
format: "#",
decimals: 0,
value: 10
});
var container = $("<div>").append(numeric);
```

then its content is is into the kendowindow

```
var content = $("<div>").append(container ).clone().wrap('<form>').parent().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
wnd.content(content);
wnd.center().open();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the kendoNumericTextBox after you used `clone()`, not before.

http://jsfiddle.net/3rbj9yks/5/